csvsimple does not show last saved entry
I ran into an issue while trying the csvsimple package, and I am unsure if I made a mistake somewhere or if it is a possible bug in the package. I have found a workaround for my issue, which I have added at the bottom, but I am curious as to the reason for the original behaviour.
Using the Data Collection method outlined on p.42 of the csvsimple-l3 manual, I tried saving some entries from a csv-file for separat uses later. But when I save three (or more) entries, the last saved entry will not show when typesetting.
After testing for a bit I found that saving additional entries would allow all previous saved entries to be shown. Only the last entry remains invisible.
I also found that the last saved entry would show, if I did not have another table before it. As I will have to reuse the same csv-file for multiple tables in the project that this is for, that would be necessary to circumvent.
MWE with code giving me the issue immediately below, while my workaround is below that.
MWE, where last saved entry (\HeSave) does not show:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
    ArtNr,  EAN,        Description,    Ha,     Ea
    123456, 123456789,  Product1,   Header1a,   Entry1a 
    234567, 234567890,  Product2,   Header1b,   Entry1b 
    345678, 345678901,  Product3,   Header1c,   Entry1c
\end{filecontents*}
 
\csvstyle{every csv}{
    before reading=\inputencoding{latin1}, 
    after reading=\inputencoding{utf8}, 
    head to column names, 
    collect data
 }

\csvstyle{TestTable}{
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    tabularray={
        row{1}={font=\large},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
    data collection=\HaSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoli
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HbSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcolii
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HcSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoliii
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HdSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoliv
}

\csvreader[ %DOES NOT SHOW IN TYPESETTING
    data collection=\HeSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcolv
}

%\csvreader[ %UNCOMMENTING THIS MAKES \HeSave SHOW. \EeSave WOULD NOT SHOW, IF INPUT
%   data collection=\EeSave, range=2,
%]{test.csv}{}{
%   \csvexpval\csvcolv
%}

 \csvreader [TestTable]{test.csv}{}{ %COMMENTING THIS TABLE OUT MAKES \HeSave APPEAR IN THE TABLE BELOW
    \csvlinetotablerow
}   
    
\bigbreak
 
\csvreader [TestTable, table head={\HaSave&\HbSave&\HcSave&\HdSave&\HeSave\\}]{test.csv}{}{
     \ArtNr & \EAN & \Description  & \Ha & \Ea 
}

\end{document}

I did manage a workaround by making the saving into a command. In addition to being easier to read, it also shows all saved entries in both situations outlined above.
Functional code with workaround
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
    ArtNr,  EAN,        Description,    Ha,     Ea      
    123456, 123456789,  Product1,   Header1a,   Entry1a 
    234567, 234567890,  Product2,   Header1b,   Entry1b 
    345678, 345678901,  Product3,   Header1c,   Entry1c 
\end{filecontents*}

\csvstyle{every csv}{
    before reading=\inputencoding{latin1}, 
    after reading=\inputencoding{utf8}, 
    head to column names, 
    collect data
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_test_seq
\DeclareDocumentCommand\testcommand{mmm}{
    \csvstyle{Saver}{
        data~collection = \mysave ,
        range=#1,
    }
    \csvreader[Saver={#1}{#2}{#3}]{test.csv}{}{
        \exp_args:Nc \csvexpval {csvcol\romannumeral#3}
    }
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {#2Save} \mysave 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\csvstyle{TestTable}{
    head to column names,
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    tabularray={
        hlines,
        row{1}={font=\large},
    }
}

\begin{document}

\testcommand{1}{Ha}{1}
\testcommand{1}{Hb}{2}
\testcommand{1}{Hc}{3}
\testcommand{1}{Hd}{4}
\testcommand{1}{He}{5}

\csvreader [TestTable]{test.csv}{}{
    \csvlinetotablerow
}

\bigbreak

\csvreader [TestTable, table head={\HaSave&\HbSave&\HcSave&\HdSave&\HeSave\\}]{test.csv}{}{
     \ArtNr & \EAN & \Description  & \Ha & \Ea 
}

\end{document}


You caught a flaw in csvsimple-l3 v2.6.0 (2024/01/19) in which the data collection=<macro> is not reset per \csvreader. I've reported it to csvsimple, see https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/issues/39.
Although usually used in a per-\csvreader basis, the effect of data collection=<macro> is global. So if it's not reset every time, the most recently set <macro> wins.
In combination of an undocumented behavior that when consume collected data=true is set, the data collection macro will be globally cleared (set to empty), in OP's first example

\csvreader[data collection=\HeSave, range=1,]{test.csv}{}{\csvexpval\csvcolv} sets \HeSave as the data collection macro and sets \HeSave to hold "Entry1a", both globally.
\csvreader [TestTable]{test.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow} globally sets \HeSave, the data collection macro in use, to empty.
The consume collected data=true is set by the TestTable style which uses tabularray option, which uses generic collected table option.
Therefore in the next \csvreader, the now empty \HeSave typesets nothing.

As a workaround, you can add data collection = \csvdatacollection to the every csv style.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.csv}
    ArtNr,  EAN,        Description,    Ha,     Ea
    123456, 123456789,  Product1,   Header1a,   Entry1a 
    234567, 234567890,  Product2,   Header1b,   Entry1b 
    345678, 345678901,  Product3,   Header1c,   Entry1c
\end{filecontents*}

\IfPackageAtLeastTF{csvsimple-l3}{2024-05-16}{
  \csvstyle{every csv}{
      before reading=\inputencoding{latin1}, 
      after reading=\inputencoding{utf8}, 
      head to column names, 
      collect data,
  }
}{
  % csvsimple-l3 < 2.6.1
  \csvstyle{every csv}{
      before reading=\inputencoding{latin1}, 
      after reading=\inputencoding{utf8}, 
      head to column names, 
      collect data,
      data collection=\csvdatacollection, % <<< workaround
  }
}

\csvstyle{TestTable}{
    late after line=\\,
    late after last line=,
    tabularray={
        row{1}={font=\large},
    }
}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[
    data collection=\HaSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoli
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HbSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcolii
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HcSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoliii
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HdSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcoliv
}

\csvreader[
    data collection=\HeSave, range=1,
]{test.csv}{}{%
    \csvexpval\csvcolv
}

\csvreader [TestTable]{test.csv}{}{
    \csvlinetotablerow
}   
    
\bigbreak
 
\csvreader [TestTable, table head={\HaSave&\HbSave&\HcSave&\HdSave&\HeSave\\}]{test.csv}{}{
     \ArtNr & \EAN & \Description  & \Ha & \Ea 
}

\end{document}


Before

After



Thank you very much, that explains a lot. I was wondering what was happening behind the scenes.

I uploaded a new version 2.6.1 (2024-05-16) to https://github.com/T-F-S/csvsimple/releases/tag/v2.6.1 and also to CTAN.
Here, data collection is reset to \csvdatacollection for every csv reader which should solve the problem.
